# show "no match found" on auto complete search list if element not exist

Tags: javascript, html, search, autocomplete

show "no match found" on auto complete search list if element not exist.

I want in my search code (autocomplete on an input field) to show a sentence like "no match found" as a div tag or something that if the element doesn't exist in my "ul list".
How can i do that?should i try another filter logic?

```js
function myFunction() {
input = document.getElementById("myInput");

document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "block";
if (input.value.length==0) {
document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "none";
}
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
    
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.show{display:block; }
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:none;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search here..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
<li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element1</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">element2</a></li>
<li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @arspro, I get errors when I run the code snippet. Could you please review and fix the code? Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

here is it give a try...

```js
function myFunction() {
input = document.getElementById("myInput");

document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "block";
if (input.value.length==0) {
document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "none";
}
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue,noMatch;
    
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    noMatch = document.getElementById("no_match");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) 
         {    li[i].style.display = "block";
             noMatch.style.display = "none";
    
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            noMatch.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.show{display:block; }
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:none;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#no_match{
display:"none"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search here..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
<div id="no_match">no match found</div>
<li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element1</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#">element2</a></li>
<li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work.it just fine for first search.if you search again it fail.

Comment: Sorry? It's working perfectly..where is the problem

Comment: search wrong word first then search the right (eg. "element1").you'll see.In fact, this is my main problem

Comment: I make some changes. please give a try now. hope it will work

Comment: Nice it’s getting close.but if you type the “element1” completely.”no match found” will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes in HTML section and JavaScript function too, hope you will get your desire output.i have also attached the code snippet, you should try with the edited code. Thank You.

```
    function myFunction() {
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");

    document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "block";
    if (input.value.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("myUL").style.display = "none";
    }

        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
     

            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML="No match Found..!!"
            
            }
        }
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .show{display:block; }
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display:none;
    }

    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }

    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search here..." title="Type in a name">
    <p id="Result">
    <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element1</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#">element2</a></li>
    <li><a class="even" target="_blank" href="#">element3</a></li>
    </ul>
```